# Minkowski sum for rectangle intersection calculation

Tags: android, algorithm, sprite, collision-detection, collision

I've been looking into the best way to determine where 2 rectangles intersect and have been looking into using the Minkowski sum.

I would be grateful if someone could explain how to determine when and where (ie, which edge) 2 rectangle collide using the Minkowski sum.

I've read a lot regarding this, but I'm not sure how to properly implement this.

Thanks

The code is:

```
float w = 0.5 * (A.width() + B.width());
float h = 0.5 * (A.height() + B.height());
float dx = A.centerX() - B.centerX();
float dy = A.centerY() - B.centerY();

if (abs(dx) <= w && abs(dy) <= h)
{
/* collision! */
float wy = w * dy;
float hx = h * dx;

if (wy > hx)
    if (wy > -hx)
        /* collision at the top */
    else
        /* on the left */
else
    if (wy > -hx)
        /* on the right */
    else
        /* at the bottom */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your rectangles are axis-aligned, then there is simple method:

rectangles A and B **don't** intersect, if

```
(A.Left > B.Right) or 
(A.Right < B.Left) or 
(A.Top < B.Bottom) or 
(A.Bottom > B.Top)
```

otherwise collision occurs.

If your rectangles are not axis-aligned, then you can use effective [separating axes algorithm](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/MethodOfSeparatingAxes.pdf)

**Edit:** Dynamic collision using  Minkowski sum:

Let's we have moving rectangle A and standing rectangle B. Let's velocity vector of A is (vx, vy). We want to find a moment of first collision and determine what edges touch each other.

At first, shrink A rectangle to the point with the same center, expand B.Width by A.Width symmetrically and B.Height by A.Height (make Minkowski sum). Now we have to find intersection of the line (ray) with rectangle. 
[image]

There are some methods, for example, we can use [Liang-Barsky line clipping algorithm](http://www.skytopia.com/project/articles/compsci/clipping.html). Note the we have not to check all intersections, because we need only the first collision - if vx >=0, check intersection with left edge and forget about right edge and so on...

Comment: Hi @MBo - I'm using simple bounding rectangles/squares that are axis aligned.  There is no rotation (or at least none that will require CD).  The problem with your method is that is doesn't tell me which edge is colliding and also if 2 sides intersect, which edge intersected first, I need this information to to react to the collision/reposition the moving sprite. Do you have any idea how I would do this as I've been looking for 2 days solid and everything I've tried so far has failed.  Help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate in a bit more detail please @Mbo, I don't quite understand what you mean.... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm 7 years late, but thought I'd share some "geometry layman" intuition I got from scratching my head at this for hours.

Attached are some notes from a problem involving this algorithm that I walked through to help me understand the relationships between the values. (Hopefully attaching notes for my response isn't too far against Stack Overflow's policies)

[image: page 1]

[image: page 2]